# how to access all array values in php?

Tags: php

This my controller code:

```
$this->load->model('catalog/manufacturer');
$data['categories'] = array();
$results = $this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getManufacturers();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $data['manufacturer'] = array(     
        'name' => $result['name'],
        'href' => $this->url->link('product/manufacturer/info', 'manufacturer_id=' . $result['manufacturer_id'])
    );
}
```

When I print this

```
print_r($results);
```

all manufactures displays. but i print this :

```
print_r($data['manufacturer'] = array( 
'name' => $result['name'], 
'href' => $this->url->link('product/manufacturer/info', 'manufacturer_id=' . $result['manufacturer_id']) 
));exit;
```

it displays only one manufacturer. I need to display all manufacturers. How can I do this?

Comment: Remove exit; because exit finish script immediately

Comment: i want to display all manufactures,but this array prints only one value,so how to use foreach for that array to display all values

Comment: I've told you: remove EXIT

Comment: Remove the exit, like said by nospor. And replace it with print_r($data['manufacturer']); Also remove the original print_r. Its a bad habit to mix variable assigning and other code.

Comment: but please understand my question i cannot access all manufactures values from this array $data['manufacturer'] = array(     
                'name' => $result['name'],
                'href' => $this->url->link('product/manufacturer/info', 'manufacturer_id=' . $result['manufacturer_id'])
            ); please tell me how to access all manufactures values from that array .but that $result displays all manufacturer values,

Comment: @user7007720 You've had two (now three) people support what you need to do to fix the script, plus additional detail from Sitethief that is also useful.  Try what has been suggested, and if you continue to have problems, [edit] your question to include what you changed and what still is not working, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOw in foreach you overwrite you variable. You must add to it not overwrite, so:

```
$data['manufacturers'] = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    //$data['manufacturers'][] - it add not overwrite
    $data['manufacturers'][] = array(     
        'name' => $result['name'],
        'href' => $this->url->link('product/manufacturer/info', 'manufacturer_id=' . $result['manufacturer_id'])
    );
}
print_r($data['manufacturers']);
```

Comment: please tell me how to display this in tpl file...i already displayed but now undefined variable occurs..this my  tpl code <li><a href="<?php echo $manufacturer['href']; ?>"><?php echo $manufacturer['name']; ?></a></li>

Comment: <li><a href="<?php echo $manufacturers['href']; ?>"><?php echo $manufacturers['name']; ?></a></li>

Comment: like this  
<li><a href="<?php echo $manufacturers['href']; ?>"><?php echo $manufacturers['name']; ?></a></li> –

Comment: please tell me how to display this in my tpl file

Comment: Your data are in `$data['manufacturers']` and int tpl you suddenly looking for `$manufactures` variable. Do you really think there is magic which will automatically convert `$data['manufacturers']` into $manufacturers?